# Coloring the area under the graph in lineplot of seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I plotted from data using seaborn's line plot whose code looks like this:

```
sns.lineplot( x=df["#Energy"], y=df["py"]+df["px"]+df["pz"])
```

and the plot I got is

[image]

now I want to color the area under it in opaque blue, how do I do that
I dont find anything relevant to that in seaborn lineplot documentation
All the efforts to help are appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seaborn doesn't seem to have such a function. However, you can use [plt.fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0]], columns=['x', 'y'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], ax=ax)
ax.fill_between(df['x'], df['y'], alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

It produces the following:

[image]